# Bash script in xcode returning Shell Script Invocation Error

Tags: xcode, shell, build

I have this script made to autoincrement the build number on every build:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" $INFOPLIST_FILE)
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" $INFOPLIST_FILE
```

I inserted it on the build phases before the "copy bundle resources". First, in the Shell Field I left the default /bin/sh but it gave me a `Shell Script Invocation Error` saying:

```
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

So i looked up what to do and I discovered that changing the Shell to `/bin/bash` could fix it. I did so and I still have the same error. It still tells me that the `Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1`. Why is it still telling me I have an error with /bin/sh if it does not exist anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I understand this question is over a year and a half old, but when searching this issue this question appeared at the top of search results. I found a different fix I wanted to share:*

Here are the error details that I received when using the plistbuddy script (I assume this is the same error the OP saw as well).

```
Set: Entry, ":CFBundleBuildVersionString", Does Not Exist
File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: /Users/*YourFilePathHere/YourAppName*.app/Info.plist
Set: Entry, ":CFBundleBuildDateVersionString", Does Not Exist
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

[image: Screenshot Command bin sh failed with exit code 1 error]

I tried to `clean` and deleted `Derived Data` without success. Turns out the actual solution was quite simple. I found that during `build` the script was trying to add the generated values to the `plist` before the `plist` was actually generated by Xcode.

[image: Screenshot Target Build Phases]

`Targets > Build Phases > Extra Version Data` is there this script is ran. 
However `Targets > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources` is where the `plist` is generated.

[image: Screenshot Target Build Phases]

Click and drag `Extra Version Data` so that it becomes listed after `Copy Bundle Resources` thus, the `plist` is built BEFORE the script tries to add the generated values.

[image: Screenshot Target Build Phases Corrected]

Then `build` and rejoice with a beer.

*(Using Xcode 5.1)*

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and found that I had a space in the filename for my INFOPLIST_FILE from a result of creating a new target and XCode appending the suffix ' copy'.  It seems that PlistBuddy can't handle that space the way this script is created.

Once I renamed the file without the space and updated the name to match in the build settings this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem after using the new Fabric Cocoapod with my Xcode project.

I had to change the Fabric script from:

`${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run ...`

to:

`"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run" ...`

because I have a space in the name of the one of the directories leading up to my cocoapods root location:

`~/Documents/My Directory Name/My_Xcode_Project_Directory/`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened for me as well.
Deleting the **Derived Data** and then **clean and build** is fixing the problem.